# Multiview Stereo 3D construction in Blender

Tags: python, computer-vision, blender, photogrammetry, 2d-3d-conversion

I intend to make a 3D model based on multi view stereo images ( basically 2D plane images of the same object from different angles and orientation) inside Blender from scratch.However, I am new to Blender.

I wanted to know if there are any tutorials of how to project a single pixel or point in the space of Blender's 3D environment using python. If not tutorial, any documentation. I am still learning about this whole 3D construction thing and pretty new to this, so I am not sure maybe these points are displayed using a 3 dimensional matrix/array ?

Basically I want to implement 3D construction based on a paper written by some researchers. Mostly every such project is in C++. I want to do it in Python in Blender, and if I am capable enough, make these libraries open source.

Suggest me any pre-requisite if you think that shall help me. I have just started my 3rd year of BSc Computer Science course, and very new to the world of Computer Graphics.

(My skillset is C, Java and Python.)

I would be very glad and appreciate any help.

Thank You

[Link to websitehttps://vision.in.tum.de/research/image-based_3d_reconstruction/multiviewreconstruction[][1]]

image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDeoB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can very likely be done in Blender, and in Python at least for small geometries / low resolution.

A valid approach for the kind of scenarios you seem to want to play with is based on the idea of "space carving" or "silhouette projection". A good description in is an old [paper by Kutulakos and Seitz](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekyros/pubs/00.ijcv.carve.pdf), which was based in part on [earlier work by Szelisky](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/CRL-93-7.pdf).

Given a good estimation of the silhouettes, these methods can correctly reconstruct all convex portions of the object's surface, and the subset of concavities that are resolved in the photo hull. The remaining concavities are "patched" over and need to be reconstructed using a different method (e.g. stereo, or structured light). For the surfaces that can be reconstructed, space carving is generally more robust than stereo (since it is insensitive to the color and surface texture of the object), and can work on surfaces where structured light struggles (e.g. surfaces with specularities, or very dark objects with low reflectance for a laser stripe)

The basic idea is to use the silhouettes of the projection of the object in cameras around it to "remove" mass from an initial volume (e.g. a box) encompassing the object, a bit like a sculptor carving a statue by removing material from a block of marble.

Computationally, you can do it representing the volume of space of interest using an octree, initialized with a minimal level of subdivision, and then progressively refined. The refinement consists of projecting the vertices of the octree leaves in the cameras, and identifying which leaves are completely outside or partially inside the silhouettes. The former are pruned, while the latter are split, and the process continues until no more leaves can be split or a maximul level of subdivision is reached. The hull of the octree is then extracted as a "watertight" mesh using standard methods.

Apart from the above paper, a way more detailed description can be found on [an old patent by Geometrix](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6999073B1/en?oq=US6999073B1) - it sold a scanner based on the above ideas around year 2000. Here is what it looked like:

[image]

Comment: That was very useful for me, thank you so much,
What I also wanted to know is the code that would enable me to do that in Blender,
I am learning Blender at the moment, but what would help me more, is a structure of code to follow so that I can implement it in Blender script.
I hope you can help me with that. @Francesco

Comment: Afraid I do not have code I can share in this area. BTW, if you found the answer useful it'd be nice if you accepted or upvoted it, so other users are more likely to find it.

Comment: My reputation is not above 15 and so I cannot upvote it unfortunately.
I will mark it as accepted as soon as I get some sort of code base from someone for Blender to proceed on from.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing-on-demand for free service. People volunteer whatever they can out of their time and kindness. Good luck.